# Segment ordered density conjecture.

Tags: calculus, general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I have a set $S\subset\mathbb {R}^2$ with the following property

(P) $\forall x,y\in S$, $\forall\mathscr{C}$ a convex set that contains $x$ in its interior, $bd\mathscr{C}\cap [x,y]\subset \overline{bd\mathscr{C}\cap S}$.

Here $[x,y]$ denotes the segment with end-ponts $x$, $y$, $bd\mathscr{C}$ denotes the boundary of $\mathscr{C}$, and "$\overline{\ \ \ \ \ }$" stands for closure.

In other words the inclusion says

$\forall z\in bd\mathscr{C},\ z=tx+(1-t)y$, for some $0<t<1$, there is $(z_n)_n\subset bd\mathscr{C}\cap S,\ z_n\to z$.

This feels like $S$ is dense in an orderly fashion in the segment $[x,y]$ (on every boundary of a convex set).

Conjecture: If $S$ has (P) then $S$ is pathwise connected (meaning there is a continuous path within $S$ that connects any two points in $S$).

My try: For fixed $x,y\in S$ define the multi-function $F:[0,1]\rightrightarrows\mathbb{R}^2$, $$F(t):=\cup\{bd\mathscr{C}\cap S\mid tx+(1-t)y\in bd\mathscr{C}\ {\rm and}\ \mathscr{C}\ {\rm is\ a\ convex\ set\ that\ contains\ } x \ {\rm in\ its\ interior}\}$$

If one could use a continuous selection theorem to get a continuous selection of $F$ then it would be done. Unfortunately, I cannot show that, for example, $F$ has convex values to use Michael's selection theorem.

P.S. Of course evey locally pathwise connected set of $\mathbb {R}^2$ has (P). The current question is exactly the converse of that fact.

Any remark is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but it seems to me that any set $S$ which is dense in $\mathbb R^2$ satisfies (P).

Comment: @Etienne Take $S=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \mathscr{C}$ where $\mathscr{C}$ is any circle. Then $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but does not have (P).

Comment: So "circle" means really "circle", not "disk"? I misunderstood that because you wrote "containing $x$ in its interior"... I understand better the picture now, thanks.

Comment: So, what if you take as $S$ the complement of the boundary of a triangle?

Comment: @Etienne You're right. I modified the statement acordingly

Comment: OK. In fact, I was about to suggest you to modify it by replacing "circle" by "closed Jordan curve".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Bernstein set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ should be a counterexample. Being Bernstein means both $B$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash B$ meet every perfect subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: So far I see that Bernstein sets are considered only in $\mathbb{R}$. Could you provide some references for the existence of Bernstein sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: It's the same construction - List all perfect sets and inductively build your Bernstein set.

Comment: See here: https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/

Comment: B does not contain any path because its complement meets every perfect set (and a non constant path contains a perfect set). Although B and its complement must be connected.

Comment: @Guest I  looked at the construction of  Bernstein sets in the link suggested.   Could you explain how  $\mathbb {R} ^2$ can be well-ordered?  Quote: "Let c denote the cardinality of the real line $\mathbb{R}$. By Lemma 2, there are only c many uncountable closed subsets of the real line. So we can well order all uncountable closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ in a collection indexed by the ordinals less than c, say $\left\{F_\alpha: \alpha < c \right\}$. By Lemma 1, each $F_\alpha$ has cardinality c. Well order the real line $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\prec$ be this well ordering."

Comment: @NeutralElement Whether this problem is still of any interest to you after such a long period I cannot know, but I just stumbled upon this question of yours. A fundamental result of set theory, belonging to Zermelo (the result and not set theory itself, although he did have many notable contributions to make :) ), says that *any* set can be well-ordered, in other words given an arbitrary set $A$ there exists an order relation $R$ on $A$ such that $(A, R)$ is a well-ordered set.